# Usando com Map<K,V> para acessar Object

Tags: java

Tenho um objeto Chave valor, onde o valor é um object

```
Map<String, String> endereco = new Map<String, Object>();
endereco.put("logradouro", "Rua Um");
```

```
Map<String, Object> aluno = new Map<String, Object>();
aluno.put("nome","Teste Teste");
aluno.put("endereco", endereco);
```

Para recuperar o nome do Aluno fazemos:

```
aluno.get("nome");
```

Mas para recuperao o logradouro do endereço como fazemos?

Tentei

```
aluno.get("endereco").get("logradouro");
```

Mas não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que fazer um cast, observe que você criou o map do endereço como object, logo o get desse map retorna um object e não o map logradouro. Acredito que isso resolve seu problema:

```
((Map<String, String>) aluno.get("endereco")).get("logradouro")
```